# Retain original paragraph spacing with HTMLbody

Tags: html, excel, outlook, vba

[image]    Sub ColdEmail()

```
Dim OutLookApp As Object
Dim OutLookMailItem As Object
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim iCounter As Long
Dim MailDest As String
Dim subj As String
Dim bod As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim signature As String

lastrow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Prospects").Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row 'change worksheet

For iCounter = 2 To lastrow

    Set OutLookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
    Set OutLookMailItem = OutLookApp.CreateItem(0)

     signature = Environ("appdata") & "\Microsoft\Signatures\"
    If Dir(signature, vbDirectory) <> vbNullString Then
        signature = signature & Dir$(signature & "*.htm")
    Else:
        signature = ""
    End If
    signature = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFile(signature).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2).ReadAll

    With OutLookMailItem

        subj = ""
        MailDest = ""
        bod = ""

        If Cells(iCounter, 13) = "*" Then

            subj = Cells(iCounter, 14).Value
            MailDest = Cells(iCounter, 7).Value
            bod = Cells(iCounter, 16).Value

            .BCC = MailDest
            .Subject = subj
            .HTMLBody = bod & signature
            .Send
        End If

    End With



Next iCounter

End Sub
```

The code above sends emails automatically to a column of e-mail addresses and it gets the body paragraph from a column in Excel as well.

I wanted my messages to include my default signature in Outlook, so I changed my code to HTMLbody.

The e-mails sent out don't retain the original paragraph spacing:

```
line 1

line 2

line 3
```

It looks like this now: `line1 line2 line3`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would echo Scott Holtzman's advice to read up on HTML. Whenever I've needed to do HTML formatting in an email, I've found that `<br>` is the most straightforward option. Using one `<br>` will move text to the next line. To create white space, (like, a blank line between paragraphs) use `<br><br>`.

You can put this right into the cell where your text is located. The brackets will mark this as HTML and it will be rendered in the email as a break rather than as readable text.

In other words:  `Thanks,<br>Cthulhu` in your excel cell, will render as 
"Thanks,
Cthulhu"
 in your email.

Answer (score 1):

It would serve you well to read up on [coding HTML](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_formatting.asp).

For now, you can do this:

To load the default signature (already set in outlook), you can do the below (and eliminate your code to get the signature):

```
With OutLookMailItem
     .Display
     signature = .HTMLBody
     ....
```

To format the HTML for the body you can do something like this:

```
'change font info as needed
bod = "<BODY style=font-size:12pt font-family:Times New Roman font-color:blue>" _
      & "<p>" & Cells(iCounter, 16).Value & "</p>" _
      & "</BODY>" _
      & signature
```

Comment: the e-mail sends properly using .BCC

Comment: i tried out this edit but my emails still dont retain the original spacing - line1line2line3

Comment: the original spacing? I am confused, because you only set the body from one cell? Are there carriage returns in this cell that creates the spacing?

Comment: yep, i am new to vba so i set my whole paragraph from one cell. i don't know what carriage returns are

Comment: can you post a screen shot of your "whole paragraph in one cell"? Do you press `Ctrl+Enter` when you are making your paragraph in one cell (creating a carriage return)?

Comment: added in my OP. i basically have the whole paragraph prepared so I reference it in my code

Comment: I see now. The answer you accepted is a good idea. I usually do it line by line in my code (mainly because I have variables in the body depending on the email that are easy to see. You could also add the `<BODY>` HTML tagging into your cell as well to set fonts and stuff.